# problem with sqlite login

Tags: iphone, objective-c, sqlite

Friend I am really so confessed  WHat should i do.
Here is my code .

@synthesize Username,Password;
  -(void)createDatabaseIfNeeded {

```
BOOL success;
NSError *error;

 //FileManager - Object allows easy access to the File System.
 NSFileManager *FileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];

 //Get the complete users document directory path.
 NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

 //Get the first path in the array.
 NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];

    //Create the complete path to the database file.
    NSString *databasePath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Journeymapper.sql"];

    //Check if the file exists or not.
    success = [FileManager fileExistsAtPath:databasePath];

    //If the database is present then quit.
    if(success) return;

    //the database does not exists, so we will copy it to the users document directory]
    NSString *dbPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Journeymapper.sql"];

    //Copy the database file to the users document directory.
    success = [FileManager copyItemAtPath:dbPath toPath:databasePath error:&error];

    //If the above operation is not a success then display a message.
    //Error message can be seen in the debugger's console window.
    if(!success)
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to copy the database. Error: %@.", [error localizedDescription]);
}

-(void)check
{

    //Get the database and connect to it.

    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *dbPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Journeymapper.sql"];



    //open the database
    if(sqlite3_open([dbPath UTF8String], &database) == SQLITE_OK)
    {
        //const char *sql ="select Username@'%@',Password@'%@' from userinformation";
        NSString *sql = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"select * from UserInformation where UserName='%@' and Password='%@' ",Username.text,Password.text];
        sqlite3_stmt *selectSatement;


        //Preoare the select Statment
        int returnValue = sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &selectSatement, NULL);
        NSLog(@"%i",returnValue);
        if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &selectSatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
        {

            NSString *user1 = [NSString stringWithUTF8String:(char *)sqlite3_column_text(selectSatement, 0)];
            NSLog(@"%@",user1);
        }
    }
}

-(IBAction)Login
{
    [self check];
}
```

problem is that here  :-Im not sure why `sqlite3_prepare_v2` isn't meeting `SQLITE_OK`.

```
if( sqlite3_prepare_v2(database, [sql UTF8String], -1, &selectSatement, NULL) == SQLITE_OK)
```

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Journeymapper.sql i think you should use sqlite instead of sql

Comment: What IS returned from the sqlite3_prepare_v2() call? The exact returned error should give you a clue. See http://www.sqlite.org/capi3ref.html#sqlite3_errcode Also note that you really should bind placeholders (UserName=? and Password=?, then set their values with the sqlite3_bind_* functions). This will avoid escaping problems, and therefore SQL injection.

Comment: It doesn't show me any error app is run but it doesn't check the qlite3_prepare_v2() where my UIALertView or NSLog for displaying results                                                                             What IS returned from the sqlite3_prepare_v2() call                                        ans:-The breakpoint jump out from the loop

Comment: Is any other way to do this if yes Send me sample code

Comment: Don't just paste your code into the question.  You need to reformat it to replace tabs with spaces and also, the code formatting only kicks in if you indent it all by four spaces.

Comment: now check it out where i am going wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you trying to prepare the statement twice?  You should be using [sqlite3_step()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/step.html) to evaluate your prepared statement.

---

On a side note, your code is vulnerable to [SQL injection attacks](http://xkcd.com/327/).  Instead of substituting the use and password string into the select statement, you should be using [sqlite3_bind()](http://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/bind_blob.html) to bind your parameters to the prepared statement.

Comment: can you give me example how to use it

Comment: @user420220: The attached blog post has an example about half way down.  http://www.icodeblog.com/2008/08/19/iphone-programming-tutorial-creating-a-todo-list-using-sqlite-part-1/

Comment: how can use sqlite3_bind () with sqlite_exec().How can i pass two qurey "one  for the passwrod and one username" and then how can i compare this with my "user.text and password.text"  which enter by the user.

Comment: @user420220: The blog post and your code between them answer all the questions.  I don't have time to write your program for you I'm afraid.

Comment: Thanks for answer.But i also have one question It's possible to tag the map with photo